# FPGA configuration - Multiple Device SelectMAP - sharing PROG line

Tags: fpga, configuration, selectmap

So I wanted to program multiple FPGAs (different images) by using a processor over SelectMAP interfaces. I plan on sharing the PROG and INIT lines across the multiple images like this:
[image: Multiple Device SelectMAP Configuration]

This issue I see is that it says in this user guide that when prog is pulsed low, the FPGA configuration is cleared and a new configuration sequence is initiated.

So how does that work with multiple devices? I see the chip selects will be unique to prevent configuring both at the same time, but if I pulse prog low, won't both devices clear the config memory and I will have to program both and not just one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you share the prog_b line, then it is not possible to reset the devices individually, unless you do it from inside the FPGA design via the ICAP. If you want to be able to reset them independently, then don't share the prog_b line. In fact, what I would recommend doing is only sharing the data, clock, and rdwr pins and keeping CS, prog_b, init_b, and done separate. That way you can easily see which devices failed to configure, instead of that something failed to configure, but you can't tell which FPGA it was. The flip side is that there are some benefits from wiring I think init_b together in terms of ensuring that the FPGAs start up together, so maybe share init_b but not prog_b or done.

Comment: So you mention that the prog_b line will reset the devices, so it this different than wiping out the configuration memory or is it just a reset. I am assuming this is just a reset since the above would never work.

Comment: Reset as in clear all configuration memory, yes. The schematic from Xilinx will work just fine if you configure all of the FPGAs at once.

Comment: I should mention that there is a distinction between reset the device and reset the design. Reset the design is just some GPIO pin that's wired to reset your user logic. Reset the device means resetting the FPGA itself and reloading the design from the configuration source - flash, etc.

Comment: So, I would pulse the program line, then start the process of configuration of all devices - 1 after the other until all three are programmed. If I stop after 1 FPGA, the other two would be unprogrammed.

Comment: Yep, and the programmed ones will be held in init until all of the FPGAs are programmed by the shared init_b line. Whether or not this makes sense in your application is a different story. The Xilinx sch assumes you always (re)configure all FPGAs at the same time. If that's not what you want, then don't share the signals. Simple as that.